# Creating an exe file for windows using mac for my Kivy app

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller, kivy-language

I've created a kivy app that works perfectly as I desire. It's got a few files in a particular folder that it uses. For the life of me, I don't understand how to create an exe on mac. I know I can use pyinstaller but how do I create an exe from mac.

Please help!

Comment: **exe for mac?** Well.

Comment: By `exe` do you mean a windows executable?

Answer (score 1):

For pyinstaller, they have stated that packaging Windows binaries while running under OS X is NOT supported, and recommended to use Wine for this.

> 1. Can I package Windows binaries while running under Linux?
>
> No, this is not supported. Please use Wine for this, PyInstaller runs
>   fine in Wine. You may also want to have a look at this thread in the
>   mailinglist. In version 1.4 we had build in some support for this, but
>   it showed to work only half. It would require some Windows system on
>   another partition and would only work for pure Python programs. As
>   soon as you want a decent GUI (gtk, qt, wx), you would need to install
>   Windows libraries anyhow. So it's much easier to just use Wine.
>
> 2. Can I package Windows binaries while running under OS X?
>
> No, this is not supported. Please try Wine for this.
>
> 3. Can I package OS X binaries while running under Linux?
>
> This is currently not possible at all. Sorry! If you want to help out,
>   you are very welcome.

Answer (score -2):

This is easy with `Pyinstaller`. I've used it recently.

Install `pyinstaller`

> pip install pyinstaller

Hit following command on `terminal` where `file.py` is path to your main file

> pyinstaller -w -F file.py

Your `exe` will be created inside a folder `dist`

`NOTE : verified on windowns, not on mac`

Comment: OP wants to create exe on mac, please see the question correctly

Comment: @Nordle, according to the `Pyinstaller` [documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/requirements.html#mac-os-x) It should be possible: `PyInstaller runs in Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion) or newer. It can build graphical windowed apps (apps that do not use a terminal window). PyInstaller builds apps that are compatible with the Mac OS X release in which you run it, and following releases. It can build 32-bit binaries in Mac OS X releases that support them.`